# como puedo hacer este navbar responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive

como puedo hacer este navbar con diseño responsivo

Adjunto codigo:

````
```import React from "react";
   import {AppBar,Toolbar,Typography} from '@mui/material'
   import './navbar.css';
   import Foto2 from "./foto2";
   import Idioma from "./idioma";
  const Navbar = () => {
return(
    <div className="formato">
        { <AppBar className="barra">
            <Toolbar className="texto">
                <div>
                 <Foto2/>
                </div>
                <div className="nombre">
                <Typography  variant="h6">
                    Tesseract
                 </Typography>
                 </div>
                <div className="menu">
                 <Typography variant="h6">
                    acerca 
                 </Typography>
                 <Typography variant="h6">
                    productos
                 </Typography >
                 <Typography variant="h6" >
                    api
                 </Typography>
                 <Typography variant="h6">
                    soporte
                 </Typography>
                 <Typography variant="h6">
                    contactanos
                 </Typography>
                </div>                  
                 <Idioma/>
                 <Typography variant="h7">
                    esp
                 </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar> }
    </div>
)
}

export default Navbar```
````

Estoy haciendo esta barra de navegacion pero tengo que darle un diseño responsivo cunado yo ocupe un pantalle de 480 px estuve intendanto hacerlo con css pero no aplica los estilos estoy usando react y material ui haba alguna forma de hacerla sin librerias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya probaste usando las media query tipo así en css

```
@media all and (min-width: 300px) {
      display: block;   
      width: 100%;
}
```

Aquí en cada caso de acuerdo al tamaño de la pantalla puedes poner el diseño que tendrá cada uno en `min-width` puedes agregar los pixeles según el caso y dentro de las llaves declarar el diseño que deberá tener cuando llegue a esos pixeles la pantalla, así podrías hacerlo responsivo

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/349408)